# Strange symbol after preg replacing

Tags: regex, preg-replace

Quick question. Im doing a **preg_replace** to clean out the words from a title:

```
$title2 = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}&;]/", " ", $title1);
```

If I'm not mistaken, that should give me ALL letters and the "&" and ";" symbols.

Howerver... I can't seem to be able to get rid of this one: —

Any tips?

**UPDATE**
@CBroe pointed out that it was show because of `&mdash;` How Can I avoid strange symbols while considering accents and similar foreign characters? such as `&Agrave;`

**UPDATE2**
This code seems to be working:

```
$title2 = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}]/u", " ", html_entity_decode($title1));
```

Apparently, adding the /u makes all the difference.

Comment: Maybe the `—` is not what it seems, but is in HTML named entity notation instead? `&mdash;` – only letters, & and ; – fits perfectly!

Comment: AH!! of course! You are right :-) However, I require "&" and ";" for accents, such as &Agrave; Anny suggestions?

Comment: Decode entities into real characters first …?

Comment: You do *not* "require" HTML entities for accents. If you're taking just a tiny bit of care to handle encodings correctly, you can use accented characters just fine  as is. If your characters are HTML entities, then a replacement expecting actual letters obviously won't work. Either replace HTML entities then, or decode them into actual letters first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seems to be working:

```
$title2 = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}]/u", " ", html_entity_decode($title1));
```

Apparently, adding the /u makes all the difference.